# Фактическое определение типа

Tags: java, jvm, полиморфизм

Может мне кто-то пояснить, каким образом в Java осуществляется фактическое определение типа объекта, какой алгоритм действий?

Comment: В заголовке объекта по известному индексу хранится ссылка на метаданные класса, с помощью которой он и достается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если говорить, о OpenJDK/HotSpot, то у каждого объекта в куче (heap) есть заголовок с двумя полями: `mark` и `klass`.

`mark` содержит хэшкод, возраст объекта и локи.

`klass` представляет собой указатель на структуру:

- в JDK 7: [`klassOop`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/hotspot/file/12b2ef172230/src/share/vm/oops/klassOop.hpp), лежащую в PermGen,
- в JDK 8+: [`Klass`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b3ee8ab233ed/src/share/vm/oops/klass.hpp), лежащую в Metaspace.

По сути это внутренний аналог `java.lang.Class`, лежащий в нативной памяти.

---

Насколько я знаю, этот момент явно не описан в спецификации JVM, и в других реализациях может быть реализовано по-другому.

---

**UPD:** В JVM от IBM порядок и набор полей заголовка другой, но и суть та же - указатель на описание класса.